# Custom NavController and custom NavHost

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I would like to use custom NavController where I manage access to different fragment for a logged user. According to documentation I should implement [NavHost](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavHost). I am not sure what is the correct way to implement custom NavController. Should NavHostFragment be extended and impelement NavHost interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A NavController (as it's designed at any rate) is really a part of the View layer and so subclassing should not be necessary or used for selecting where the user goes.

An alternative is to use views/view models to go to a different part of the nav graph based on a value (e.g., a LiveData) in the view model.